# Give a google map an overlay image while keeping map movable

Tags: html, css, google-maps

Hello I am using a google map on my site. I want to give it an overlay using an image while keeping the map movable (user can drag around and zoom)

What I did so far:

I created the map, then I used a psuedo `:before` element to call the image I want to be the overlay.

I set this psuedo element overlay to fill the entire map, and placed it on top using `z-index`.

It looks fine, but since the psuedo element overlay is on top of the map, the controls of the map do not work.

Is it possible to keep the overlay on top of the map, while preserving all functionality of the map?

Here is the JS fiddle link:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/s69qnkcn/)

Thanks!

Comment: The only solution I can think of would be to use pointer-events: none on the overlay, but that only works in modern browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a CSS-only solution you can use

```
pointer-events: none;
```

on the overlay.

https://jsfiddle.net/s69qnkcn/1/

Works only for modern browsers though, IE11 and up: http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for! thank you! i will accept your answer when it allows me to

Comment: glad I could help. If you need support for older browsers you should probably use a javascript fallback though.

Comment: for sure, when you say older browsers, which browsers are you talking about? according to this http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events most browsers support pointer events

Comment: Yes, the new versions of all browsers support it. By old I mean IE10 and lower. You can see the older versions of the other browsers, too, if you click the little "show more" button above the graphic. But all other than IE have supported it pretty much for forever.